# Why does my C program produce strange printf output?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

My source code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    char info[80];
    int started = 0;
    puts("data=[");
    while (scanf("%f, %f, %79[^\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info) == 3) {
        if (started)
            printf(",\n");
        else
            started = 1;
        printf("{latitude: %f, longitude: %f, info: '%s'}", latitude, longitude, info);

    }
    puts("\n]");
    return 0;
}
```

I have a data file gpsdata.csv as follows:

```
42.363400,-71.098465,Speed = 21
42.363327,-71.097588,Speed = 23
42.363255,-71.096710,Speed = 17
```

I get

```
./geo2json < gpsdata.csv
data=[
'},titude: 42.363400, longitude: -71.098465, info: 'Speed = 21
'},titude: 42.363327, longitude: -71.097588, info: 'Speed = 23
{latitude: 42.363255, longitude: -71.096710, info: 'Speed = 17'}
]
```

It looks like the end of the line is somehow overwriting the beginning of the line.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "`%79[^\n]`" isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data file uses Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`; carriage return + newline, as opposed to normal OSes' `\n` (newline)). The carriage return is printed, and moves the cursor to the beginning of the line every time.